# org-protocol and org-capture won't work together

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I used this manual to setup an org-protocol: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-protocol.html
But with (require 'org-protocol) the variable org-capture returns this error:

```
org-capture-select-template: Symbol's function definition is void: org-contextualize-keys
```

also by typing something like following in shell

```
emacsclient org-protocol://capture://http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Findex.html/The%20title
```

same error happens. store-link protocol works though. 
How can I make emacs undertand org-capture? I'm using emacs 24.2 on ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 0):

I have no such problem with

emacs -q --eval "(require 'org)"

<kbd>f1 f</kbd> shows that `org-contextualize-keys` is defined.
The version is emacs 24.3.1 on ubuntu 13.04.
You should try to build your emacs from source: http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/emacs/.